# How to increase volume above the system's maximum volume?

Tags: windows-xp, google-chrome, firefox, audio

Sometimes I feel watching some youtube in Chrome has very low volume even if I turn everything to 100%.

Are there any ways to increase volume above the system's maximum? I know `IndieVolume` does, but that didn't support some of my applications.

Comment: Are you increasing main volume/application volume/both? There have been times when I thought damn this is quiet and realized I had not turned up the applications volume.

Comment: OS: WinXP SP3. In my control panel volume control, there's no application volume control.

Comment: I really wish Youtube would do some basic sanity checking of the audio before publishing things.  Too-quiet audio, heavily clipping audio, etc.  It's easy to detect.  Why don't they?

Comment: *> Is there any tools can increase volume above the system's maximun? [sic]*   Um…   I assume that you checked to make sure that both the master volume and video volume are at 100%, but what about the wave volume in the sound-mixer? One options it to download the video and watch it in a video-player like VLC and crank up the volume and/or use the graphics-equalizer/preamp.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid this is a issue on googles end and there is nothing you will be able to do as it is a problem within chrome/youtube itself and not your computer, I've experience the same thing with multiple OS's, always in chrome with youtube.

Answer (score 2):

Install Ubuntu Linux (you can dual boot [aka. duel boot with Windows]), and then open gnome-terminal and do

```
sudo passwd
sudo su root

apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get ubuntu-restricted-extras
apt-get install pavucontrol
exit

pavucontrol
```

And there you go ;)

> pavucontrol: PulseAudio Volume Control

**For Microsoft Windows:**
See [**here**](https://superuser.com/questions/493485/windows-7-8-tool-for-amplifying-sound-equivalent-to-pavucontrol) for the pavucontrol-equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

**2 Ways To Boost Windows Audio Above the Maximum Mark**

**1. Enable Loudness Equalization in Realtek Drivers**

This trick has been tested on the Realtek drivers. Hopefully, it should work on other sound drivers too but we can’t guarantee that. Also, before you continue, if you are using Realtek drivers then please update them to the latest version and restart your computer.
Having done that, open Control Panel and search click on the Sound icon. Make sure you are viewing the settings in icon view and not in category view.
After you open the Sound settings, right-click on speakers and click on the Properties option from the context menu.

[image: sound dialog box]

In Speakers properties, navigate to the Enhancements tab and check the option Loudness Equalization . After you enable the option, you will notice that there will be an increase in the maximum volume of the speakers and it will be around 150% when compared to the old volume output. To reset the sound back to the system default, just disable the option from properties and save the settings.

[image: Speaker Properties]

I understand that not all users might find the settings on their respective computers and that’s where you can use DFX Audio Enhancer for Windows.

**1. Use DFX Sound Enhancer**

DFX is a nifty app for Windows that boosts the sound quality across all the programs that are installed on your computer. The tool is a freeware with an option to extend the features by paying for a full license that’s not cheap (almost $39.99). After you have installed the application, just turn it on and use the dynamic boost slider to increase the volume of your system. In the free version, you can only boost to level 5 (that’s 150%) while in the paid version you can boost up to 200%.

[image: DFX Audio]

There are other parameters as well that you can change the value of to enhance the sound coming out of your system. The 3D sound however is only available for premium users. The website offers a sale time to time wherein you can purchase the license at a discount.

Comment: Very well written answer.