# How can I amplify the sound/audio output of a particular program?

Tags: windows-7, windows, audio, google-voice

I'm a frequent user of Google Voice, and I have issues hearing certain callers.  Whenever this occurs, I have to turn the volume on Windows all the way up to 100%, and I *still* would like it louder.

As you can guess, doing this also turns all the other system sounds up to full-blast, which is very undesirable during a phone call.  I know that you can change the volume of individual programs in Windows 7/8, but this would only let me *restrict* the volume of the other programs (assuming the overall volume is at 100%); I want to actually *amplify* the audio.

Is there any way I can **amplify** the audio output of **an individual program**/process?

I understand this will cause audio artifacts (especially if any clipping happens), but this is acceptable in my case given that I only want to amplify a particular program.

Comment: [This question](http://superuser.com/questions/493485/windows-7-8-tool-for-amplifying-sound-equivalent-to-pavucontrol) may be related. You could probably use some information from its answers. You could set up a virtual audio device, make it louder and select it as an audio output in that particular program.

Comment: @IOXenus thanks for the comment, somehow I missed that question.  That being said, the majority of the answers there deal with increasing the overall system volume; I'd like to only focus on a particular application... **However**, I think [Virtual Audio Cable](http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac.htm) might work here (the linked answer shows how to combine VAC with another program to amplify the signal, and I see the VAC changelog for v4.11 states "Added volume boost feature" so it may be possible entirely with VAC).

Comment: @IOXenus I'm stuck with my Linux laptop all weekend, so I won't get a chance to test VAC until next week; if I get a chance, I will test it in a VM.  That being said, at this point, I'm pretty sure VAC would be the best option, and seeing as you brought it to my attention, you're more than welcome to type up an answer detailing VAC if you would like.

Answer (score 1):

Although it's not amplification, it's easy to increase the volume of only one application using the built in Windows 7 mixer. (I'm on Windows 7, but should be similar on 8)

Open the Volume Mixer (Click the volume icon) and select the "Mixer" link to see the list of applications. You can expand the window to see all the applications at once.

First, lower the main volume all the way down. (or part way if desired) This will in turn lower all the applications open.

Then, raise the volume on the application you want to be higher. The main volume will rise while leaving the others down, or scaled appropriately.

Comment: "I know that you can change the volume of individual programs in Windows 7/8, but this would only let me restrict the volume of the other programs (assuming the overall volume is at 100%); I want to actually amplify the audio."